# problem with elasticsearch query, range malformed query, expected END_OBJECT but found FIELD_NAME

Tags: elasticsearch

I cant figure out what's wrong with this query. Both "range" and "exists" work independently, but together I get `parsing expection` and `range malformed query, expected END_OBJECT but found FIELD_NAME`. Can someone figure out what's wrong with this query?

```
{
"query": {
  "range":{
     "@timestamp":{
        "gte":"2019-08-04T11:00:00",
        "lt":"2019-10-04T12:00:00"
     }
  },
  "exists": {
      "field": "params.zone"
  }  

},
"_source": ["@timestamp", "params.zone"]
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to combine several queries like you're doing with `range` and `exists` you need to use [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) and decided which of your clauses are mandatory (`must`), optional (`should`), filter (`filter`), or shouldn't be presented in results (`must_not`)

Query which would work could look like this (you're clauses are mandatory in this example):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "2019-08-04T11:00:00",
              "lt": "2019-10-04T12:00:00"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "params.zone"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": [
    "@timestamp",
    "params.zone"
  ]
}
```

Comment: @Mehrdad could you please upvote the answer as well, if it helped you